# Use of Imagesloaded plugin in the RWD theme

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery, rwd-theme, rwd

If you look at the layout file page.xml of the RWD theme you will find a declaration like:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/imagesloaded.js</name></action>
```

Now, I am fully aware of what this plugin does but I am unable to see where magento makes use of this plugin specifically.

Bizarrely, removing the plugin causes no errors or breakages. So, I was wondering if someone could kindly explain where magento makes use of this plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Basically this js file checks/ Detect when images have been loaded. You can read / check more about it here https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded.
and Magento uses it here skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/configurableswatches/product-media.js
skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js

Comment: xMageStore, aware of how the plugin works just not in correlation to magento.

Comment: So, if I am not using configurable swatches is it safe to remove the plugin?

Comment: @VaishalPatel yes you can remove it if you're not using swatches.